# Element K of an object pointer vector turns null after pushing N-th element into the vector from element K-1

Tags: c++, vector, memory-management, null, segmentation-fault

I recently started to learn OpenGL. I had an idea of testing my skills 
after each part of the learnopengl.com tutorials, and I am 
currently after chapter https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Shaders

So I have created a simple pong game, and while debugging I have noticed strange behavior. 
 The game I have created crashes after some time, but always after one of the players gets a point.
It's important to note that each game object has an update function that I call every frame,
 and I keep pointers to all of the game objects in a STL vector.

I have analysed a bit of the code and found nothing bad with it, so i fired up gdb and wrote some "std::cerr" information.
This is what I found out:
1. The game crashed while updating one of the objects (obj->update())
2. The game always crashed after new point was awarded to a player, making the game object pointers vector contain 32 elements. If I used GAMEOBJECTS.relocate(33) before the game started, the vector contained 33 elements while crashing.
3. The game crashed while updating the fifth Game Object from the vector. It must be noted here, that the ball object is number four, and Ball::update() contains the code which creates new GameObjects (points).


From these information I deduce, that when I create a new object, and push it's pointer to a vector, the vector has to relocate itself, because It doesn't have enough capacity. 
This, in turn, leads to some strange memory-mess which I do not understand, as I'm just starting to learn c++ programming.
That is also what makes accessing the fifth element of the vector impossible.
I'm struggling to find a way to solve this problem, but my biggest concern is understanding WHY is this happening.

The code is too big to be pasted here, so I put it on github:
https://github.com/carul/opengl_pong

I will still describe what I think is the most important:

```
for(auto && obj : GAMEOBJECTS){
  obj->update();
  obj->draw(VBO);
}
```

So this is the loop I use to draw and update my game objects.
I think there is nothing special about it, other than It updates objects one after another.

```
void Ball::update(){
   ///...
   if(boundingLeft < -0.96f){
    this->setPosition(0.0f, 0.0f);
    this->speedmodif = 0.8f;
    this->angle = 0;
    Point * point = new Point(GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    point->create(POINT_DATA);
    point->indice(POINT_INDICES);
    point->setPlayer(2);
    point->name = "POINT";
    point->setPosition(0.93f - 0.03f*scorep2, 0.9f);
    scorep2++;
    GAMEOBJECTS.push_back(point);
  }
  if(boundingRight > 0.96f){
    this->setPosition(0.0f, 0.0f);
    this->speedmodif = 0.8f;
    this->angle = M_PI;
    Point * point = new Point(GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    point->create(POINT_DATA);
    point->indice(POINT_INDICES);
    point->setPlayer(1);
    point->name = "POINT";
    point->setPosition(-0.95f + 0.03f*scorep1, 0.9f);
    scorep1++;
    GAMEOBJECTS.push_back(point);
  }
  ///...
}
```

This is a fragment of the ball's update function. This piece of code is responsible for creating a new point. Ball is a derived class of class Object.
GAMEOBJECTS is defined like this:
`std::vector<Object * > GAMEOBJECTS;`

Sorry for a long post, I tried to provide all the information I have.
Big thanks for reaching this part of the text, and thank You for any help

Here is a screenshot of gdb and the game during the crash:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Don't you save a reference to a vector's element, push an element to the vector and then use that reference? All references and iterators are invalidated if the vector has to reallocate storage to increase its capacity.

Comment: first: you're leaking memory. for beginner i recommend to never use the keyword "new". use a unique_ptr instead, if you need a pointer. As for the crash i assume it could be related to a re-allocation of the vector which can happen on push_back. Cant be sure without seeing the repsonsible peice of code.

Comment: What do you mean by "save"? I'm creating a new object and pushing the pointer to it to the vector. The pointer is then removed because I access all elements using the vector anyway, so I don't need it.

Comment: @skeller well that's nothing new, I said it in my post that I also assume this to be related to the re-allocation. But could you please tell me where I'm leaking the memory? I would like to fix it.

Comment: @Cuaox every new allocates memory which you never seem to clean up

Comment: I do remove the points for example when the game is restarted, and as far as my operating systems knowledge goes, the OS will make sure to clean up. I do not remove 6 gameobjects because they are used all the time (displayed and updated all the time) and I just know the OS will remove them anyway. Other than that, I remove and add all objects when I need - I actually have to do it, if i didn't they would be drawn on the screen.

Comment: *and I just know the OS will remove them anyway.* -- And then, later requirements may request that you move that code to a portion of the program that gets called in a loop.  Your code should be ready to be called from in any part of the program, and without fail.  Relying on the OS to correct your "mistakes" is not a good way to write a program.

Comment: Should I really consider it such a big problem? If later requirements would imply moving this code to a loop I would just do it no problem, all objects have names and I keep track of them in my code so deleting them doesn't seem to be a problem. I still don't know why I shouldn't use the "new" keyword, I've been coding in C and asm for quite some time and I think I understand how memory works (except STL vectors of course). Besides, I can't really think of any later requirements for a pong game, Isn't this discussion a bit pointless since we are trying to over engineer stuff?

Comment: *I still don't know why I shouldn't use the "new" keyword, I've been coding in C* -- C is not C++.  Second, memory leaks -- you should be using a smart pointer, not raw pointers and `new`.  If you're not using `new` as a means to instantiate derived objects from a base class (i.e. for polymorphism purposes), there is little, if any reason to be using `new` in a modern C++ program.  You should be using `std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr`, etc.  Also note that *many* experts in the C++ community, some that you may have heard of, also discourage using `new` in end-user applications.

Comment: Now this is a solid explanation, thanks. It actually turns out that I actually use new to instantiate derived objects in my code. I will try to experiment with unique_ptr in the future as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this loop

```
for(auto && obj : GAMEOBJECTS) {
    obj->update();
    obj->draw(VBO);
}
```

`obj` is a reference to the vector's element. In `update()` you `push_back()` into `GAMEOBJECTS`. This operation invalidates `obj` reference if vector's capacity is not enough to accommodate the new element.

Comment: Thank you!
Actually after reading your comment I replaced my auto loop with "for(unsigned i = 0; i < GAMEOBJECTS.size(); i++)" and it works now!

Comment: @Cuaox, I would recommend not to modify the vector while iterating over it. Such code is hard to reason about and is error-prone.

Comment: Yes you are right, do You maybe have any information on how game engines do this? The also have to update stuff and I've seen many people add entities during the update step

Comment: @Cuaox, my comment was not about the algorithm, but about the code. You can add entries during update if you have to, but I don't like the way you do it: it is not obvious for the reader that `obj->update()` modifies `GAMEOBJECTS`. To find a bug one has to carefully check what `update()` does internally. No space here to be more specific. I suggest you ask at SO Code Review what they think about this code and how it can be improved.